# Dynamically Creating Menu Structure using Knockout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a requirement to display menus and submenus but I have to populate the structure using a service response.

Below is the sample response I am getting from the service.

```
{name: "Item A",
    url: "url of Item A",
    title: "sometitle",
    children: [{
               name: "Child1 of A",
               url: "url of Child1 of A",
               title: "sometitle",
               children: [{
                            name: "Grandchild of A",
                            url: "url of Grandchild of A",
                            title: "sometitle",
                            children: [{
                                       name: "Grand Grand child of A",
                                       url: "url of Grand Grand child of A",
                                       title: "sometitle",
                                       children: []
                                       }]
                          }]
               }]
},
{name: "Item B",
url: "url of Item B",
title: "sometitle",
children: []
},
{
 name: "Item C",
 url: "url of Item C",
 title: "sometitle",
 children: []
 }
```

All the parent nodes Item A, Item B, Item c are displayed as menu buttons,with children as submenus. I have no information on the depth of the children.
Service can have any number of parents and any level of children nodes.

So,at runtime I have to create the menu structure.

Can i achieve the same using pure javascript ui/li tags? I want to create ui, li tags dynamically ,using a recursive function, which gives me a similar tree structure as shown in the response, Any pointer?

Thanks

Tani

Answer (score 1):

I've faced this requirement myself, I'll present my solution:
I defined a Knockout template to render one item. This will be used to render the first 'tier' of items in your tree-like datastructure. The 'magic' is that the template will render the item's children, *using the template itself*. So the idea is basically a 'recursive template'. (Sorry if my explanation is a bit vague, the code below should make it clear.)

The template could look like this (suppose you store the service response in an array called `items`):

```
<script type="text/html" id="treeItem">
<li class="item">
    <a href="#" data-bind="text: name, attr: { href: url, title: title }"></a>
    <ul data-bind="template: { name: 'treeItem', foreach: children }"></ul> // Magic is in this line
</li>
</script>
```

Consume the template for the first tier of items:

```
<ul data-bind="template: { name: 'treeItem', foreach: items }"></ul>
```

Here is a Fiddle demonstrating the solution: http://jsfiddle.net/xsjxc8jd/

Edit: And it didn't even require observables :)

Comment: Thanks Hans,Can i achieve the same using pure javascript <ui>/<li> tags? I want to create <ui> <li> tags dynamically ,using a recursive function, which gives me a similar tree structure as shown in the response, Any pointer?

Comment: What do you mean with pure JavaScript? No Knockout?